# Wrong value returned after calling a sequence of functions

Tags: c

I need some help regarding my program. I cant seem to find a solution regarding the year I insert.. I just get some weird year in return, what am I doing wrong?

**example:**
after entering *10.02.1994* I should get *27* as return, but instead I get *4327832*

What's the solution here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int eingabeZulassungsdatum() {
    int tag, monat;
    int zulassungsjahr;
    printf("Bitte geben Sie das Zulassungsdatum ein (in der Form tt.mm.jjjj):");
    scanf_s("%2i.%2i.%4i", &tag, &monat, &zulassungsjahr);
    printf("Zulassungsjahr 1: %i \n", zulassungsjahr);
    if (tag < 1 || tag>31) {
        printf("Bitte geben Sie den richtigen Tag an!");
    }
    if (monat < 1 || monat>12) {
        printf("Bitte geben Sie den richtigen Monat an!");
    }
    return zulassungsjahr;
}

int alterBerechnung(int zulassungsjahr) {
    int diesesjahr = 2021;
    int alter;

    alter = diesesjahr - zulassungsjahr;
    return alter;
}

void ausgabeAlter(int alter) {
    printf("Das Auto ist %i Jahre alt", alter);
}

int main() {
    printf("Programm zur Berechnung des Alters eines Autos\n\n");

    eingabeZulassungsdatum();
    alterBerechnung(eingabeZulassungsdatum);
    ausgabeAlter(alterBerechnung);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `alterBerechnung(eingabeZulassungsdatum);` Why are you passing a function into `alterBerechnung` which is defined to take an `int`? Did you mean to save the result of calling `eingabeZulassungsdatum()` and passing that to `alterBerechnung`? Same with `ausgabeAlter(alterBerechnung);`

Comment: you should let us know what is `scanf_s`, otherwise its  not a standard function in `C`

Comment: Are there no compiler warnings?

Comment: I'm not getting any compiler errors since its running, but the function is wrong. I need the value "zulassungsjahr" into "alterBerechnung" and then that value into "ausgabeAlter"

Comment: `int e = eingabeZulassungsdatum(); int a = alterBerechnung(e); ausgabeAlter(a);` If it is still not clear why your code is wrong then suggest you review your C book. Your code currently makes no sense as it is using functions as if they are integers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int eingabeZulassungsdatum() {
    int tag, monat;
    int zulassungsjahr;
    char dot;
    printf("Bitte geben Sie das Zulassungsdatum ein (in der Form tt.mm.jjjj):");
    scanf("%d%c%d%c%d", &tag, &dot, &monat, &dot, &zulassungsjahr);
    printf("Zulassungsjahr 1: %d \n", zulassungsjahr);
    if (tag < 1 || tag>31) {
        printf("Bitte geben Sie den richtigen Tag an!");
    }
    if (monat < 1 || monat>12) {
        printf("Bitte geben Sie den richtigen Monat an!");
    }
    return zulassungsjahr;
}


int alterBerechnung(int zulassungsjahr) {
    int diesesjahr = 2021;
    int alter;

    alter = diesesjahr - zulassungsjahr;
    return alter;
}


void ausgabeAlter(int alter) {
    printf("Das Auto ist %d Jahre alt", alter);
}

int main() {
    

    printf("Programm zur Berechnung des Alters eines Autos\n\n");
    ausgabeAlter(alterBerechnung(eingabeZulassungsdatum()));

    return 0;
}
```

Input: `10.02.1994`

Output:

```
Programm zur Berechnung des Alters eines Autos

Bitte geben Sie das Zulassungsdatum ein (in der Form tt.mm.jjjj):Zulassungsjahr 1: 1994 
Das Auto ist 27 Jahre alt
```

If you want to pass values returned by functions to other functions, you need to call the function inside other function, just like above. This way the value returned by a function will be used as arguments for other function.

Changes made:

- I replaced scanf_s by scanf
- I used %d for inputting integers instead
  of %i (I am not sure where %i is used)
- Inside scanf we need to take
  care of the `.` as well. So I used a varaible of type char with the
  name `dot`. As `.` in our string comes two times, I used the dot
  inside scanf two times

Answer (score 0):

You've got a fundamental misunderstanding about how functions are used:

```
eingabeZulassungsdatum();                 // line 1
alterBerechnung(eingabeZulassungsdatum);  // line 2
ausgabeAlter(alterBerechnung);            // line 3
```

Your `eingabeZulassungsdatum` function is declared as returning type `int`:

```
int eingabeZulassungsdatum() {
```

and it *does* return an `int` near the end:

```
return zulassungsjahr;
```

But when you call it on line 1 in your `main()` function, you're not saving the value that's returned. Instead, you're trying to pass the function name into the call to `alterBerechnung()` on line 2, and then doing the same with that function on line 3. **That is not how functions are used.** Instead, you need to *use the value returned by the function*. That can mean capturing it in a variable, like this:

```
int datum = 0;
datum = eingabeZulassungsdatum();
alterBerechnung(datum);
```

Or, you can make the call to the first function inside the call to the second:

```
alterBerechnung( eingabeZulassungsdatum() );
```

You can even extend that idea to the third function call:

```
ausgabeAlter( alterBerechnung( eingabeZulassungsdatum() ) );
```

Doing that isn't a great practice, though... when you have too much going on on a single line, things get difficult to debug. You're usually better off using local variables to capture the return values, and then passing those into the next function:

```
int datum = 0;
int alter = 0;
datum = eingabeZulassungsdatum();
alter = alterBerechnung(datum);
ausgabeAlter(alter);
```

This way is a lot easier to debug because you can see the result of each step in the debugger.

> after entering 10.02.1994 I should get "27" as return, but instead I get 4327832

The name of a function used without parentheses is actually a pointer to the function itself. So when you wrote:

```
alterBerechnung(eingabeZulassungsdatum);
```

you were passing a pointer to the compiled code for `eingabeZulassungsdatum` as the parameter for the call to `alterBerechnung(...)`. There are actually times when you *do* want to pass an entire function, and not just its result, as a parameter in a call to another function, but this is not one of those times. ;-)